# How to encrypt and decrypt a file with Qt/C++?

Tags: c++, qt, encryption, qt4

I want to create a program, which can encrypt and decrypt a complete file with an individual password. Is there any way to manage this in Qt and/or C++ and how?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've never used it myself, but I've heard great things about [QCA](https://api.kde.org/qca/html/index.html). It's cross platform, uses a Qt-style API and Qt datatypes.

Answer (score 11):

www.cryptopp.com is a very complete C++ library with implementations of most algorithms.

The actual program (select file, read, obtain key, encrypt etc) should be piece of cake.

Answer (score 6):

Old, I know, but try [Botan](http://botan.randombit.net/). It's actually used internally by Qt Creator 2.0. If you download the Qt Creator 2.0 sources you can find a copy of Botan 1.8.8 all set up for the Qt build system (qmake).

Answer (score 5):

Neither Qt nor the C++ standard library have encryption built-in. You'll need another external library to handle encryption.

Answer (score 3):

Qt doesn't provide functionality to encrypt/decrypt.

QCryptographicHash only generates hashes. It is not what you are looking for.