# How to choose an encryption algorithm to encrypt/decrypt a file?

Tags: c++, qt, encryption

Recently I am writing a QT program that require me to encrypt/decrypt a file. I am new to encryption where I am totally don't know anything on how to do encryption using programming. After googling a while, I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262081/how-to-encrypt-and-decrypt-a-file-with-qt-c) which is very similar to my objective. 
They suggest to use crypto++, but my problem is when I reach there, there are plenty of selection for encryption. I just want to encrypt a file, doesn't need a sophisticate one, and don't need a password to open the file. Only my program can open and read that file.

May I know how to choose the encryption algorithm that is suite for me?

THanks @!

Comment: You are not providing enough information.  From whom are you trying to hide the file content?  (i.e. other users who can see the file but not your application executable, people who can see both but not run the latter, people who can run your application).  How important is it that they can't see it?  Are you trying to make it hard enough that it's not worth their time, or virtually impossible?  How determined and IT-savvy will they be?  What type of file content is it (e.g. numbers, text, executable code)?

Comment: How about the traditional ROT13 encryption? It works without a password, too... ;-)

Comment: It is easy to choose the decryption algorithm; it must be the inverse of the encryption algorithm.

Comment: @Tony: I am trying to hide the content of the file from user, anyone who use the program. It doesn't matter a computer savvy or a clerk. The content of the file are a set of configuration setting that control how the program will behave. It store the setting configuration, some sort of INI file, but I store it in XML format. The reason I encrypt it is because I worry the user will mess up the program behaviour. I was thinking a simple one will do, I don't need a very sophisticate algorithm. :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the explanation of purpose in your reply to my comment on the question, it seems like there's little point going beyond low-level obfuscation of the XML.  You could, for example, simply XOR the file content with an arbitrary value (e.g. AA hex), or a small number of values that you use on successive characters (AA, 23, B7, ...), then loop to use AA again.  Doesn't sound like there's much benefit in using a real encryption library: anyone that determined to screw up their software's operation will find a way anyway....

Answer (score 9):

Maybe a short (very short) intro to cryptographic algorithms would be helpful:

- Symmetric encryption: uses the same key to encrypt and decrypt. Examples include DES, AES, and Blowfish.
- Asymmetric encryption: requires a certain key to encrypt (public), and a different key to decrypt (private). Examples include RSA, DSA, and ElGamal

For this application I'd suggest a symmetric algorithm, AES would probably be a good fit (AES256). Regardless of what you use though, there will always be a key (otherwise it wouldn't be very good encryption). The simple approach would be storing the password directly in the program. This would allow your users to avoid typing anything, but a determined attacker could easily find the password even in a compiled binary.

This is about as specific as I can get unless you provide further details. I hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest 'real' symmetric algorithm is probably blowfish, there is [sample code in 'c' and'c++'](http://www.schneier.com/blowfish-download.html) which is very easy to integrate into your code

There is an independant [QCrypto](http://delta.affinix.com/qca/) lib (not part of the main Qt src) but it's possibly a little more complicated than you need

Comment: No, someone asking "what cipher should I use" should never be told "go implement that cipher". They should be told to use a standard algorithm from a high-quality library.

Comment: The link is to ready to use code for a standard algorithm  by both the author of the algorithm (Bruce schneier) and a bunnh of others

Comment: RC4 is a lot simpler to program than Blowfish.

Comment: @rossum - interesting I hadn't looked at RC4. I just remember being able to understand blowfish!

Comment: The problem is that sample or reference code is not necessarily a high-quality implementation. There are 14 different versions there, with no indication of which ones have been vetted for cache attacks, timing attacks, etc. For the questioner's particular use case, that won't matter, but someone reading this could be steered wrong to grab any old thing that seems to work, which is a *really bad idea*.